# Display a message that counts no of search results?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to modify my search on a controller so that it is able to count the number of matching results typed by the user in a search string.So that a user would search for a movie name and there was 1 matching film a message would say “1 movie matched your search criteria: 'terminator'”.

**So far this is my code , I have no errors and it searches the data fine but doesnt count the no of results**.If anybody knows what I need to do in order to get the search to display a message then that would be very helpfull.The search facility works but I need to count how how many matches there are to the data & display a message if there are no results or if there are and how many.

Thanks

```
public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString)
    {
        ViewBag.NamesSortParm = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "Name desc" : "";
        ViewBag.MoviesSortParm = sortOrder == "MovieID" ? "Name" : "Director";
        var Movies = from s in MoviesRepository.GetMovies ()
                    select s;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            Movies = Movies.Where(s => s.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                                   || s.Director.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
        int count = Movies.Count();
        if (count == 0)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "No matches found";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = " Results";
        }  }
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "Name":
                Movies = Shows.OrderByDescending(s => s.Name);
                break;
            case "Director":
                Movies = Movies.OrderByDescending(s => s.Director);
                break;
            default:
                Movies = Movies.OrderBy(s => s.Synopsis);
                break;
        }






        return View(Movies.ToList());





    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a typo to me.  Replace this line:

```
ViewBag.Message = " Results";
```

with this:

```
ViewBag.Message = count + " Results";
```

Also, make sure to put ViewBag.Message in the View somewhere:

```
<div> @ViewBag.Message </div>
```

Comment: Ok thanks il try that , no im not displaying the viewbag message in the view would that be the same as in the controller?, and I assume i put that in the div of the search? in the view?.

Comment: Yeah, the ViewBag.Message won't display automatically.  Just add <div>@ViewBag.Message</div>, or whatever, somewhere in the View.